# how to mix views (html+css+js) between express.js (node.js) and backbone.js

Tags: model-view-controller, view, backbone.js, express, socket.io

I am starting to learn Express.js (for Node.js) and Backbone.js. I have researched lots of documentation and tutorials, but there are some details i still haven't catched up, and there is no information related to it. I hope somebody could help here:

One of my biggest issues are the VIEWS. I understand how you can build up your MVRC in your backbone.js app.js, your MVC on your Express.js app, how to persist on the backend (express) via JSON, using Socket.io for real time, etc. But, how do you design VIEWS?

Both frameworks offer their own VIEWS, but is obvious that if you are using Backbone.js, is because you want to build up the VIEWs on the client side (HTML,CSS,jQuery and JS) with Backbone, and not with Express (Jade and templating). And if you use Express.js is because it offers more tools than Node.js, like authentication, session control, data base,etc.

How do you mix it up? i have seen some examples on internet like this book (O'Reilly Media):

http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/

specifically, on their github source code related to "option7" for a TodoList app.

Here, they mix up both technologies (Backbone.js and Express.js with MongoDB). They do data persistant between client and server, connection to Redis, etc, **but i still don't understand why they use Jade and /views for main HTML templating on Express.js, but CSS, jQuery and images inside /public on Backbone.js.**

Shouldn't we build up the HTML5,CSS3 and JS entirely in Backbone.js? Whats the point of inyecting HTML templates from the backend through /ROUTES, if you want all your MVC on the front-end?

thank you very much and hope to get an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

**One of my biggest issues are the VIEWS. I understand how you can build up your MVRC in your backbone.js app.js, your MVC on your Express.js app, how to persist on the backend (express) via JSON, using Socket.io for real time, etc. But, how do you design VIEWS?**

The views in Express.js are templates which can be rendered  and returned to the client/browser through HTTP.

**How do you mix it up?**

You have a client-side and a server-side not sure what you mean with mix it up. If your browser needs data you can get it with a request to the server.

**Shouldn't we build up the HTML5,CSS3 and JS entirely in Backbone.js?**

Most of the time you would.

**Whats the point of inyecting HTML templates from the backend through /ROUTES, if you want all your MVC on the front-end?**

This is mostly to speed up web pages so you don't have to re-render the entire page but only a part.

Comment: ,thanks for your answer. When i write about "mix it up", i mean what i have seen on lots of examples (for instance, the famous TodoList using socket.io and express.js that i wrote before), that is coding CSS and Backbone javascript on the front-end, and HTML (Jade templates) on the back-end. I can't find examples where all the HTML,CSS and jQuery is built on the front-end (/public directory), leaving to Express.js just the back-end logic (persistant, database, sessions, etc).

Comment: Templates in Express.js aren't in the public directory but in the views directory. The reason is because they are rendered on the server and then passed to the client. So you will almost never see pure html files when using a framework. This isn't something special in express this is how most web frameworks do it.